# How to read from text file line-by-line and split the line by a character?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm writing a Bash script. My problem is I want to read from the text file line-by-line and split the line by a character. I want pure Bash code.

Let's say I have this in the text file:

**Format: (name;username;code)**

```
John Doe;johnDoe;534092
John Dor;johnDor;923845
Joan Doe;Joan;232423
```

I want to know how to split the string (line) by character ";".

I need to know this because of what I want to do next: I want to read this text file and for every name in the file make a new user (with the same home directory as name), the password should be the code, and default should be Bash.

I'm reading the file with `while read line ...`.

Comment: What have you tried?  If `;` is giving you problems, have you tried converting it to e.g. %: `sed -e 's/;/%/g'` (single quotes keep bash from thinking the line is terminated)

Comment: I've read about IFS but I don't like the solution.

Comment: Even better.  It's got exactly what you want.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/split-string-based-on-delimiter-in-bash

Comment: onvert epoch time

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
while IFS=';' read -r fullName userName password; do
    useradd ... # $fullName, $userName, and $password are available
done < users.txt
```

Comment: @JohnDoeTheOne I tried this verbatim at the command line and it works. Make sure you don't have any typos (like `$fullname` vs. `$fullName`).